# Why can't the Tkinter Button configuration of a Class be modified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am constructing a simple hex editor in Python using Tkinter. I want to be able to indicate selection of a value (the "0000"s) in the GUI by changing the colors of a pressed button. 
To implement this, I instantiated each button as a class inside a for loop and put each instance into a list to reference them later in the code. When I attempt to alter the Button API properties of the classes in the while loop, the IDLE prints an error when the hex editor is closed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Files/Python/hex editor.py", line 64, in <module>
    ml.button.configure(bg='#00FF00', fg='#000000')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1479, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1470, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame.!button"
```

The intended behavior of the button is that when any "0000" is clicked, the selected button will become green and remain so until another button is pressed. (i.e the pressed button will turn green and the previously selected button will turn black)

Source Code:

```
from tkinter import *

selected_i = 0
selected_j = 0

data_w = 16
address_w = 8

class mem_location:
    def __init__(self, row, column, data):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.data = data
        self.button = Button(subframe,
                             text=self.data,
                             font=('Consolas',9),
                             bd=0,
                             command=self.select)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button.configure(bg='#000000', fg='#00FF00')

    def select(self):
        selected_i = self.row
        selected_j = self.column        

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
root.title('Hex Editor')
frame = Frame(root,
              padx=30,
              pady=10,
              bg='black')
frame.pack()

ml_list = []

for i in range((1<<address_w)>>4):
    subframe = Frame(frame,
                     padx=10,
                     bg='black')
    subframe.pack()

    addr_label = Label(subframe,
                       text=hex(i<<4)+"    ",
                       bg='black',
                       fg='#00FF00',
                       width=5)
    addr_label.pack(side = LEFT)

    for j in range(16):
        ml_list.append(mem_location(i, j, '0000'))

root.mainloop()

while True:
    for ml in ml_list:
        if selected_i == ml.row and selected_j == ml.column:
            ml.button.configure(bg='#00FF00', fg='#000000')
        else:
            ml.button.configure(bg='#000000', fg='#00FF00')
```

I am currently in the process of learning about Tkinter. Why can't I modify the class's Button configuration and how can this be fixed?

Comment: If you execute `mainloop` first, then the `while` loop won't start until after the user closes the window. If you execute the while loop first, then mainloop will never run and the window will never appear. In general, Tkinter doesn't play nicely with infinite loops. It's better to do just a little work periodically, then yield control back to the mainloop. This is typically done either with `root.after` or threading.

Comment: You seem to be trying to configure the buttons after the window has been destroyed. Why are you doing that after the window has been destroyed?

Comment: In this case, what you need to do is put the body of that while loop into an event handler callback, which runs one time whenever the selection changes, instead of running over and over forever.

Answer (score 0):

The code after `root.mainloop` will not run until the window is not closed, so you are trying to modify the buttons after the window has been closed.

Instead, you could move the code in the `submit` method like this:

```
from tkinter import *

# You don’t need selected_i and selected_j anymore

data_w = 16
address_w = 8

class MemLocation:

def __init__(self, data):
    # Same code without self.row and self.column

def select(self):
    for ml in [ml_ for ml_ in ml_list if ml_ is not self]:  # All elements except this one
        ml.button.config(bg='#000', fg='#0F0')
    self.button.config(bg='#0F0', fg='#000')

# Same code here

root.mainloop()
#END
```

Note that I renamed the class according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?) but there are many other improvement possible like making MemLocation inherit from `Frame` or `Button`, or adding event listeners to make the code cleaner.